# github and composer. pulling repository branches

Tags: git, composer-php, dependency-management

Composer cannot find the branch I want to clone from in the respository supplied in my json file. the error I get is:

```
 [UnexpectedValueException]
 Could not parse version constraint development: Invalid version string "dev
 elopment"
```

I assume I cannot say, go to this location, clone from this branch?

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name": "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core",
                "version":"development",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Core.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"development"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core": "development"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You've just got the syntax wrong. You need to tell Composer to use a branch and then the branch name. So instead of:

```
"require": {
    "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core": "development"
}
```

assuming your branch is called 'development' it should be

```
"require": {
    "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core": "dev-development as 2.0.0"
}
```

The `2.0.0` to the right of the 'as' is the alias that your branch will be aliased to. This allows Composer to treat your branch as satisfying any other requirement for `AdamKyle/Aisis-Core` in the project with your branch version as version 2.0.0.

Comment: Hi Danack, when we assume that "development" is the branch I want to have. The your solution will just checkout the master. Is there still something missing?

Comment: @ownking Possibly. The syntax above definitely checks out the branch 'development' but composer will still composer.json from the master (or rather default) branch.

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this problem myself.  I think the correct approach is to reference the branch under source and then give it a version of dev-branch:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name": "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core",
                "version":"dev-development",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Core.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"development"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core": "dev-development"
    }
}
```